# Unable to INSERT time in data base using MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to INSERT time which is in format `"Tue, 14 Jan 2014 19:56:09 +0530"` using query

```
   INSERT INTO monitor (Date, Name ) VALUES ('$Date','$Name') ";
   mysql_query($query) or die ("query failed");
```

This query execute without any error but when I look into values inserted it was found that value of time in different other than what is in `$Date` , value inserted is `"0000-00-00 00:00:00"` other than `"Tue, 14 Jan 2014 19:56:09 +0530"`. Is any their anything I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5):

1. You need to format it using [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) inline with your `INSERT`. For example, `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y');` ... Use the specifiers in [this table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
2. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.
3. You have no error handlers

Comment: @Alexxus Are you implying OP should continue to use `mysql_` functions?

Comment: True @Alexxus, but it's excellent advice. It's standard practice here on StackOverflow to warn people when they're opening themselves up for SQL Injection trouble, which can be a career ender.

Comment: No, but your points 2 and 3 have nothing in common with the solution of the problem. They are only a warning/note and shouldn't be numbered in my opinion

Comment: @Alexxus I'll make sure not to use lists when you're on SO reading my answers.